# How do the available annotated version of Discources on Livy differ?

Tags: italian-language, niccolo-machiavelli, discourses-on-livy

I saw [this answer by Tsundoku](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/6659/necessity-or-benefits-of-reading-livy-before-machiavellis-discourses-on-livy/6881#6881) from 2018. I was interested to learn how the available annotated versions differ.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Literature Stack Exchange. Is your question about annotated *editions* (i.e. of the original Italian text) or about annotated English translations? (Or about annotated translations into other languages?) (If it's about annotated editions, I'm not entirely sure we have the required expertise on this site.)

Comment: Annotated English Translations. Was specifically wondering which you would recommend,  as your citation of other sources used within Discources beyond Livy seemed really useful  to access directly when reading a translation.